# IntelliJ + Selenium + Appium Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS emulator 5554

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I'm trying to open a Android device using Appium + Selenium. I have already made the virtual smartphone and I get an Error.

This is My Java code:

```
         @Then("^I want to build a smartphone$")
         public void i_want_to_build_a_smartphone() throws MalformedURLException {

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "emulator-5554");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
            mobiledriver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            //Connect to the webDriver server
    }
```

And this is the Error I'm getting

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS emulator 5554. The following are available: emulator-5554 (8.1.0)
```

Build info: `version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'`

Comment: make sure your emulator is up and running!

Comment: I have Appium + a Virtual Smartphone running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your platform version must be the os version of android not the
> emulator name.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1"); 
//here you must put your emulator os version instead of 7.1
```

> and you have two **Browser_Name** capabilities. Try removing one of
> them.
>
> Also make sure your emulator is running

Answer (score 4):

Always use following command to list available device `adb devices`

As per info in server logs

> > > The following are available: emulator-5554 (8.1.0)

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.1.0");
```

Appium server logs are very helpful.It is always suggested to read them very carefully. They are self suggesting fix many time